# How to get a last DML operation in Oracle 10g-11g

Tags: oracle

I can get a number of last `INSERT's`/`UPDATE's`/`DELETE's` from `SQL%ROWCOUNT` var. Also there exists a way to get a last DML time of each row.

But is there a way to get a last DML operation performed on a table - `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I need a way to find a name of DML opration itself. It means something like string constant `INSERT` if the last op was `insert into T...`.

Answer (score 5):

With this query you will see your last DML event by loonking on last change , most recent date is the last operation

```
  SELECT TABLE_OWNER, 
   TABLE_NAME, 
   INSERTS,
   UPDATES,
   DELETES,
   TIMESTAMP AS `LAST_CHANGE`
FROM  ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
WHERE TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY LAST_CHANGE DESC;
```

[image]

But the only way to use it its separating the DML events in differents querys or adding three differents last_change per dml event.
In any case you tell me your doubts

Comment: This is correct only for DMLs since the last time statistics had been collected. SELECT max(ora_rowscn) should be the proper method, but it is unbelievably slow if you have a lot of legacy tables and running 11g.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on user session auditing for that schema that is running the command.  Then look at the SYS.$AUD table to see what that operation was with the timestamp.  You can also turn on application context, which allows you using the package DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO to track the specific DML in tables like gv$sql using MODULE and ACTION columns.  I'm sure there are other was as well.